# Django OneToOne reverse relationship does not allow null values

Tags: database, python-2.7, one-to-one, django-1.8

I have this architecture (very simplified)

```
from django.db import Models

class MainClass(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.CharField()

class OtherClass(models.Model):
    c = models.IntegerField()
    main = models.OneToOneField(MainClass, primary_key=True)
```

Which means my **MainClass object has an attribute named otherclass, because of the existence of the reverse relationship between these models**.

My problem is if I specify valid values for MainClass.a and MainClass.b, but None for MainClass.otherclass. I get the error

***ValueError: Cannot assign None: "MainClass.otherclass" does not allow null values.***

I understand there cannot be OtherClass without MainClass (it doesn't make sense), but why the opposite situation is also causing an error? Other way: **Why cannot be MainClass without OtherClass?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this is a normal behaviour in Django 1.8](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14368), although the restriction [has been removed in Django 1.10](https://github.com/django/django/blob/04e13c89138d48c20e774a2b6bf06796f73ac0fe/docs/releases/1.10.txt#L482)

So, This isn't an error.