# Django ManyToOne reverse relationship allows null values

Tags: python, django-models, many-to-one

I know that a reverse relationship can have a null value, now I am asking 
if I can force the reverse relationship to be not null.

Very simple example:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    pass

class Exam(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='exams')
```

I want to go from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7msc.png) (the code above) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMHFv.png). I don't want  a subject without an exam at least.

I have already read the documentation for django 2.1 and searched on google and stackoverflow.
This is like the oposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594225/django-onetoone-reverse-relationship-does-not-allow-null-values).

**P.S.** This is not really an important matter and I think in most cases is not advisable to force something to be not null, but maybe you just want to translate from the diagram or concept to implementation literally.

Comment: Hello! I found this in the django changelog: [1.10 changelog](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/releases/1.10.txt#L662). I don't really know if this changed in later versions but looks like django is not checking for null in the foreignkey relationship. Let me know if you find anything new! I'm curious about why wouldn't Django check this.